# Emberjs computed firing and logic running, but not updating the view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a computed property on a controller which I can see is being called when it should (when the route loads and when a button is pressed) however the `newsItem` record isn't being removed from the view.

```
  filteredNews: computed('user.read', function () {
    const newsItems = get(this, 'newsItems');
    const userClassifications = get(this, 'user.classification');
    const userRead = get(this, 'user.read');

    newsItems.forEach((newsItem) => {
      userClassifications.forEach(userClassification => {
        if (newsItem.get('classification').includes(userClassification)) {
          newsItem.unloadRecord();
        }
      });

      if (userRead.includes(newsItem)) {
        console.log("read: " + get(newsItem, 'title'));
        newsItem.unloadRecord();
      }
    });

    return newsItems;
  }),
```

The `console.log(...)` is being called each time, so I know the logic is correct.

Is there an obvious reason this isn't working as I expect?

Comment: It could be something to do with the use of the `unloadRecord` function. Unloading records seems to be have half-broken by the latest versions of Ember Data (check for example [#4972](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4972)). Personally I just don't use the `unloadRecord` function anymore, because it has given me a lot of trouble it the past...

Comment: I agree with you, and I've seen that issue, but what's the easiest and cleanest alternative?

Comment: Just filter the data, don't unload them from the store. It does not matter much you still got 'unused' model in the store, unless you got a lot of them. Most browsers (even mobile ones) may use a lot of RAM nowadays anyway. No need to bother yourself with that issue, until it becomes a problem.

Comment: which version of ember-data are you on?

Comment: @runspired sorry I should have included that in the question: `"ember-data": "~3.0.0"`

Comment: I would recommend filtering. unloadRecord doesn't seem the correct action here even if it did work as a "client side delete"  (which it is not).

As for why they maybe aren't removed, unloadRecord can't actually unload a record if it is still in use by any relationships. There were also some bugs I recently fixed with unloadRecord and peekAll (available in the 3.3 canary) which might be in play.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense about the unloadRecord not working with relationships, my newsItem does have a bunch of them. Is there current examples for client side filtering floating about? Or are you suggesting I filter server side?

Comment: Just to put another reason not to use `unloadRecord` here: side effects in computed properties should be considered as a bad practice.